# Why the lack of the trailing slash in url adds :8080 to redirect?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have two website on an Ubuntu/Apache server. 
One is in directory

```
/var/www/html/dir1
```

and is configured as virtual server in apache with FollowSymlink option activated. Replies to

```
http://example.com
```

The second is a webpage index.html in

```
/var/www/html/dir2
```

To obtain a simple way to link the second page to url

```
http://example.com/dir2
```

I made a soft link inside /var/www/html/dir1 to /var/www/html/dir2 named dir1 and all went ok.
Visiting

```
http://example.com/dir2/
```

lead to the page index.html in /var/www/html/dir2.

So far so good.

Though, visiting

```
http://example.com/dir2
```

(note the lack of the trailing slash)
cause the redirect to

```
http://example.com:8080/dir2/
```

Why in this case the port gets added? How can I easily remove it?

EDIT: I need to remove the port because from index.html some post request is made and the :8080 part is causing me some cors problems.

EDIT: Virtual Host conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/dir1/drupal"
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dir1-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/dir1-access.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/dir1/drupal/">
        Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Allow from all
        Order allow,deny
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

htaccess in dir1

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "/fb/|/phpMyAdmin/|\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Make Drupal handle any 404 errors.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Override PHP settings that cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and drupal_initialize_variables() in
# includes/bootstrap.inc for settings that can be changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc                 off
  php_flag magic_quotes_sybase              off
  php_flag register_globals                 off
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off

  php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
  php_value post_max_size 100M
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  RewriteRule ^js\/(.*)$ /sites/all/modules/ets/jslib/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule (.*)jslib\/\d+\/(.*)$ $1jslib/$2 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule (.*)experiments\/\d+\/(.*)$ $1experiments/$2 [L,QSA]
  RewriteRule (.*)exp_packages\/\d+\/(.*)$ $1exp_packages/$2 [L,QSA]
  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you show `VirtualHost` entry of `example.com`? Also add full .htaccess here.

Answer (score 1):

Add this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NE,R=301]
```

and retest in a new browser or completely clear browser cache.

Comment: It's a good solution, but the website is a lot more complicated than what I described to explain the situation and adding a trailing slash in *all* cases sounds a bit scary to me. It is possibile to add this only in the case the request is specifically to http://example.com:8080/dir2?

Comment: Does `dir2` also have a .htaccess? Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: nope. there is a 301 redirect to the url with the :8080 part inside

Comment: Ah sorry my bad. Change my suggested to `RewriteRule ^dir2$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NE,R=301,NC]` and retest after clearing browser cache.

Comment: Still no fortune ^^'

Comment: Change `301` to `307` and then test in chrome tool to verify if `307` shows up or not.

Comment: it does show. I'm start thinking there's something going on i'm not taking account of...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153403/discussion-between-anubhava-and-sasha-grievus).